# Caching a large dataframe in database

Tags: mysql, django, pandas, caching

I was trying to cache a large pandas dataframe to using django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache backend into MySQL database. It works for 300,000 items but not anything bigger (e.g. 400,000 items). Can I increase the maximum length for the cache value? Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from django.core.cache import cache, caches

cache.set('data', pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(300,1000))) # It works
cache.set('data', pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(400,1000))) # It doesn't; no error, just no change in database
df = cache.get('data')
# It returns a dataframe with 300 rows × 1000 columns
# But I expect 400 rows x 1000 columns
```

Comment: What errors are generated?

Comment: No error, but it returned the older dataframe that is smaller in size.

Comment: MySQL's default max_allowed_packet is 4MB, wonder if this is the reason

Comment: if there is one (reason) its historical (hysterical maybe even too). No ill effects should come from setting it large.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the reason was MySQL 5.7's default value for max_allowed_packet was 4194304.

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

has solved the problem. Thanks danblack for the advises.